# swift user location - update if move

Tags: ios, swift, location

So I have been able to get the users location via the following code.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
      if status != .authorizedWhenInUse {return}
    print("test LOCATION BELOW")
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
      let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

        print("UUID: \(String(describing: uuid)) locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")

  }
```

However I want to watch the users location and if they move update their location.

I am wondering how do I get this code to keep checking for the users location?

My

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
  locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()}
```

I get it popping up the request and I approve it but it does not run the code

Comment: Once you have called `startUpdatingLocation` - You will start getting calls to the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method

Comment: I don't have a func called didUpdateLocations can you give an example please.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can get the location data. The code is similar to yours but with a bit of change and additions.

First check if you already have user's permission to get their location data.

```
    func isLocationServicesEnabled() -> Bool {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
            case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                return false
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                return true
            @unknown default:
                return false
            }
        }

        return false
    }
```

If this method returns false you can ask for authorization.

```
// Initialize manager in your viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
   locationManager.delegate = self
   // Do other stuff
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   // Check for auth
   if isLocationServicesEnabled() {
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
   } else {
      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
   }
   // Do other stuff
}
```

Finally in your CLLocationManagerDelegate implementation get the coordinates.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
     guard let location = locations.last?.coordinate else { return }
     // Use location.latitude and location.longitude here
     // If you don't want to receive any more location data then call
     locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: what if I am placing my code inside the FirstViewController.swift

Comment: Then you can move the implementation to your FirstViewController. Just copy and paste the second code block to your `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @RussellHarrower I've updated my answer with `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` functions.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check that you have user's permission to get their location data

```
func checkLocationServicesAuthorization() -> Bool {

         if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .notDetermined:

                 return false

            case .restricted, .denied:

             //code for open settings screen in user’s phone

                 return false

            case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:

                 return true

            default:

                 return false

            }
        } else {

             //code for open settings screen in user’s phone

        }
        return false
    }
```

And

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()

   locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
   locationManager.delegate = self

}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

   super.viewDidAppear(animated)

   if checkLocationServicesAuthorization() {

      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

   } else {

      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
   }

}
```

You can use delegate method `didUpdateLocations` of `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and don't forgot to connect delegate `yourLocationManager.delegate = self`

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

            // Call stopUpdatingLocation() to stop listening for location updates, other wise this function will be called every time when user location changes.
            // yourLocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }

            let latitude = String.init(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)
            let longitude = String.init(userLocation.coordinate.longitude) 

            print("\(latitude), \(longitude)")

}
```

Comment: It seems not to be firing the function now